# MS Access: Why Does Form.Popup Disable Form.Activate?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events, popup

This phenomenon apparently is known but Google does not reveal the reason.

In MS Access, the Activate (and Current) events do not occur for PopUp forms.

The [online documentation for the Form.Activate Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.activate) states

> The Activate event doesn't occur when a form receives focus back from
> a dialog box, popup, or another form.

but, whether this is true or not (my navigation code doesn't trigger the phenomenon) and leaving aside the question why it should be, it also is true that the Activate event does not occur for PopUp forms under any circumstances, even if no other forms are open and the PopUp form is opened by double-clicking on it in the Navigation Pane.

This seems to have something to do with the form (or the record, in the case of the Form.Current event) receiving focus but (in both cases) we know that it does because controls on the form trigger their GotFocus event.

So, it seems, for PopUp forms, the form receives the focus but the Form.Activate event does not occur and a record receives the focus but the Form.Current event does not occur.

Again, others have observed this behavior but it is not documented and no obvious reason for it exists.

**The questions are**:

- Is this a bug?
- If not, why does it occur?
- Is there a workaround to trigger Form.Activate for a PopUp form, or is one left with just moving code to Form_Load() (or, in a form wrapper, conditionally calling the same code in both Form_Activate() and Form_Load(), depending on Form.PopUp) or hacking a control's GotFocus event?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "initialize" as it is not exactly being "Activated" but is being created when you double click on it in the Navigation Pane therefore initialize should work.

Comment: I have never used nor seen any code for Activate event. Confirmed, not triggered when form is set as Popup. Current event does run. @RicardoA, I don't see an "initilize" event in Access.

Comment: Initialize isn't a Form event.  Activate is and occurs when a Form receives the focus.  Form event order is Open > Load > Activate > Current.

Comment: Are you talking about popup forms with a record source? Or forms opened through `DoCmd.OpenForm` with acDialog? Because those second ones have some oddities since they freeze running code until they close

Comment: Opening a modal pop-up form, stops code execution (where the open was called) and the form has the focus - you cannot move it away from the form. So there's nothing ready to activate - the form is constantly activated until closed.

Comment: @Kostas K, this isn't a modal popup, just a popup.  Form.PopUp = Yes and Form.Modal = No.  Hypothetically, were it modal, meaning having focus exclusively, it would meet the textbook/published definition of Form.Activate and only would prevent other forms (or objects) from receiving focus (thus blocking their Activate events).  No other forms are open, however, and this form isn't modal to begin with.

Comment: @Erik A, yes, this is just a common form with a linked table as RecordSource. Also, as noted in the OP, it is opened by double-clicking on it in the Navigation Pane.

Comment: Please provide a full [mre]. You can use the hidden `Application.SaveAsText` method to provide the form as text. Make sure to create it using Create -> Form design to avoid excessive noise in the export.

Comment: @Erik A, I tried but the file contents exceed the character limit for the Web interface.  To be clear, I created the form using Form Design as recommended.  Thoughts?

Comment: You could try a link to pastebin. I can replicate the lack of the activate event (can't tell if bug or just undocumented), but not the current event, that should always fire, so I'd want to check if I can replicate using your form, and check for obvious errors (e.g. is `Form.OnCurrent` set to `"[Event Procedure]"` and is the handler signature correct)